# Convert HTML string to Excel file in Web API C# and Download via Angular 8

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, angular8, export-to-excel

I have dynamic HTML content which I want to convert it to excel in web api C# and return that converted file via `HTTPResponseMessage` to Angular 8. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: It would be good to include more details about your code for others to help. What does your HTML content look like? How is it generated on the API side? Also do you want to generate a XLSX or XLS?

Answer (score 0):

you can convert HTML on Angular side itself. Try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-export-as

Comment: Although its not my requirement. but let me try this and will get back to you. thanks

Comment: do you have any demo link?

Answer (score -1):

Excel is microsoft, c# too. Check for a non-complicated JSON. You may want to search on : https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=excel+to+json 4th link.

- C# will retrieve excel data
  Have you done that before ?

You can either 
- create HTML page from server and send it to Angular. 
- Make JSON suits for excel.

Careful with browser object such as window by picking up solution 1.
Check out the libraries.

Comment: i have a html template which i am dynamically creating on run time. I want to convert it to excel and then convert that file in HttpResponseMessage. I think you didn't get the question!

Comment: So step 2 to end. Is that ok html ? You inspire from this. fs the tag you not mentioning .